# cannot install torchvision 0.12.0 gpu in anaconda

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, torchvision

after fighting to install for GPU pytorch with anaconda on linux ubuntu, I have a new problem how to download torchvision for GPU any recommendations?
I have installed it and run yolo v7 successfully with pip, but I don’t want to work with pip, because in my anaconda path I have the rapids of NVIDIA.
thank you in advance[image]

Comment: solved while I have active the conda : pip3 install torchvision

Answer (score 0):

Solved while I have active the conda:

```bash
pip3 install torchvision
```